# How to extract value in a xml using lxml in Python

Tags: python, lxml

```
<XMLReport><Report>
<Preflight errors="0" criticalfailures="0" noncriticalfailures="0" signoffs="0" fixes="0" warnings="10">
  <PreflightResult type="Check" level="warning">
    <PreflightResultEntry xml:lang="en-US">
      <Message>PDF/X-1a:20000 : PDF/X-1a:20000 output intent is missing </Message>
      <StringContext>
        <BaseString>PDF/X-1a:20000 : %PDFXVersion% output intent is missing</BaseString>
      </StringContext>
    </PreflightResultEntry>
  </PreflightResult>
</Preflight></Report>
```

I want to get all value/text in `<Message> </Message>` element using lxml in Python.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Question title should have your question and not what you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy from the [lxml tuto](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html):

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> s = """<Report>
<Preflight errors="0" criticalfailures="0" noncriticalfailures="0" signoffs="0" fixes="0" warnings="10">
  <PreflightResult type="Check" level="warning">
    <PreflightResultEntry xml:lang="en-US">
      <Message>PDF/X-1a:20000 : PDF/X-1a:20000 output intent is missing </Message>
      <StringContext>
        <BaseString>PDF/X-1a:20000 : %PDFXVersion% output intent is missing</BaseString>
      </StringContext>
    </PreflightResultEntry>
  </PreflightResult>
</Preflight></Report>
"""
>>> root = etree.XML(s)
>>> for message in root.findall('Preflight/PreflightResult/PreflightResultEntry/Message'):
    print message.text


PDF/X-1a:20000 : PDF/X-1a:20000 output intent is missing 
>>>
```